# CSV import: Problem with comma as multiple value separator (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, import, products, csv

I have to import products with CSV Products Import (*System->Import*) in Magento 2.

But I have problems with the *Multiple value separator*. If I choose the standard separator **comma**, it doesn't import product data completely. For example I have comma in **description** field, it is importing only the text until first comma. The rest of text is cut off. The same with **additional_images** where is only the first image imported. I have this problem with **all** product fields.
I tried to use *quotation marks* and *apostrophes* without any success.

Another *Multiple value separator* isn't working either because the fields **categories** and **additional_images** doesn't support another one.

So how can I prevent the problem with comma separator?

Comment: If I use "|" as Multiple value separator I get this error by _Check Data_: 

**Wrong URL/path used for attribute additional_images**  

In CSV file in column additional_images is: /t/e/test.jpg|/t/e/test2.jpg

Comment: Solved! The _Multiple value separator_ is hardcoded for _additional_images_ in **vendor/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Validator/Media.php**. I have to change _const ADDITIONAL_IMAGES_DELIMITER = ',';_ to my delimiter sign.

Comment: No it is not hardcoded...you change it with the `multiple value seperator` http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116635/magento-2-csv-import-how-to-escape-commas-in-additional-info

Comment: @StevieG @Guest I had the same problem in Magento 2.1.0 and also found it was hardcoded as a comma in the file Guest showed (though for me the path was `vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Validator/Media.php`). Changing the 'Multiple value separator' didn't affect this field. Changing it hardcoded to a ; fixed the problem, though obviously not a permanent solution. Seems like a bug to me.