# Magento 2 csv import : How to escape commas in additional_info?

Tags: magento2, attributes, import, csv, custom-attributes

I am importing products via .csv import.  I have an additional_attribute field that contains commas.  Commas are the delimiter within additional_attributes, and when i try to import my products, all of the additional attribute fields that contains commas get cut off after the first comma.  How can i prevent this?

I defaulted to adding a product with a comma in the additional attribute field through the admin and exported it.  It looked normal, as shown below at "the battlefield, draw".  But if i try to import that same .csv file the text will be cut off after "battlefield"
I tried a forward slash(backslash?) to no avail. I even surrounded the text in double-quotes for the import... no dice...

```
    color=White,magic_card_number=125,magic_cmc=4,magic_expansion=Alliances,magic_flavor_text=<p>coming soon</p>,magic_power=1,magic_rarity=Common,magic_rules_text=<p>Flying</p>
<p>When Carrier Pigeons enters the battlefield, draw a card at the beginning of the next turn's upkeep.</p>,magic_toughness=1,magic_type=Creature,manufacturer=Wizards of the Coast
```

Comment: I changed the DEFAULT_GLOBAL_MULTI_VALUE_SEPARATOR in \vendor\magento\module-import-export\Model\Import.php to ^ and still when i import an additional_info field w/ commas it cuts off after the first comma.

Comment: UPDATE: just checked the table importexport_importdata after the above change.  The full text is in that table, but in catalog_product_entity_text it is still cut off at the first comma.  Maybe import works, but the db write is flawed?  HELP!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to modify any code or your import file (as provide above) to get this to work.

You can change the separator used for the 'additional_attributes' column by changing the value for the 'Multiple value separator' on the product import screen in the admin area to something other than a comma (see image below).

[image: Product import multi value separator]

Please note I tested this using Magento CE 2.0.7, adding an attribute called 'magic_rules_text' and adding the same content in your original question.

I initially had the same issue when the value for 'Multiple value separator' was left at ','.  I changed this to ';' and the full content imported to the attribute correctly.

Comment: Yeah but then how do you change the seperator in the csv?

Comment: @StevieG don't use Excel. In any other spreadsheet programm you can set the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse it with the editor you're using to open CSV file. That is the main culprit. I opened my CSV in simple text-editor and below hack worked for me.

**CSV file content**

sku|additional_attributes|updated_at
01|tab_highlights=a,b,c$#$tab_custom=CUSTOM$#$tab_deliveryscope=a,b,c|12/20/18

**Explanation:**
I separated my fields with **vertical bar(|)** and for multiple values in single column i used custom separator that is highlighted in above content **$#$** used to separate the multiple values of second column ( additional_attributes )

**Import Setting on Magento Dashboard**

[image: Dashboard Import Setting]

Helped taken from this article :  [Guide to Import Magento2](https://www.alexcorradi.org/blog/a-guide-on-how-to-import-export-products-in-magento-2)