# What characters are NOT allowed in which fields within Magento?

Tags: special-character

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto
```

We are having lots of problems and it looks more and more that the issues are connected to spaces and illegal characters we have entered into various fields within products and categories.

For example, I just noticed we have commas (,) in category names and these did not transfer correctly when doing an Export/Import from Magento 2.4.2-p1 into Magento 2.4.5-p1.

*I plan to go through the 2000+ products manually and check for any potential problems with this including the attributes but I would appreciate a clear directive on what is and isn't allowed.*

Another example - I googled and read the following:

"SKU so long as it's under 64 characters, non-null, and unique should work." Is that true and are there absolutely no spaces allowed in SKUs?

**What about other fields such as category and product names, the URL field, image names, attributes etc.?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SKU should be less or equal to 64 in length or else it will throw error ***SKU length should be 64 characters maximum***

1. SKU cannot be submitted null as it is required
2. SKU will get unique if it not while submitting (add increment no as suffix)
3. Best to use only -,_ with letter and number as per needed
4. No issue with space (that happen with URL generation)

If you are using comma in product name as example (,) consider as delimiter so that you can change it to some other sign like (| or ||) for Field separator as mansion over this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203766/77554)